# Click on jstree node, rebuild tree with that node as the root

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I think the subject is reasonably clear.  :)

I'm a jstree newbie and have tried to parse the docs, but I'm getting
a bit stuck with this one.  I have the following code:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
   "json_data" : {
       "data" : [
           tree.company
       ]
   },
   "themes" : {
       "theme" : "smb",
       "dots" : false,
       "icons" : true
   },
   "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
   $('#tree').jstree.refresh(data.inst.get_selected());  // FIXME
});
```

The tree loads and displays just fine, but when I click on the node
that I want to become the new root of the *displayed* tree, I get an
error at the line marked FIXME.  I've tried all kinds of things with
no joy, and would really appreciate some help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I get an error"? What's the error?

Comment: Precisely which jstree plugin are you using ? I ask as there are a lot of versions floating around and some different plugins with the same name that I've come across.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The error is Uncaught TypeError: Object function (settings) { ...

Comment: @RussC I'm using latest version from http://www.jstree.com/ (pre 1.0 fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entire tree needs to be refreshed, then the tree's container can be referenced and refreshed.

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    $.jstree._reference(data.inst.get_container()).refresh(); //(data.inst.get_selected());  // FIXME
}).bind("refresh.jstree", function (event, data) {
    alert("Refreshed!");
});
```

If just the node needs to be referenced in select_node:
    data.rslt.obj[0];

Or another round about way to get it (same node as above):
    $.jstree._reference(data.inst.get_container()).get_selected();

You may also need to destroy and rebuild the tree:
 $.jstree._reference("#tree").destroy();
I know this may seem wasteful, but you are replacing the root node anyways.

Comment: This worked a little better than mattytommo's answer, in that the tree refresh seemed to redraw everything (it collapsed fully).  Plus thanks for the tip of binding to the refresh event.  But the bad news is that whether I used data.inst.get_selected() or data.inst.get_container(), the end result was the same.  The root of the tree was the same as it was before, not the node I had clicked on.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that you wanted the clicked node to become the root node. Why not delete the tree and redraw a new one? $.jstree._reference("#tree").destroy(); Then call the same function used to create the tree the first time around. You may need to replace the json data tree.company with another variable that changes with node click.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it does work - just two questions: 1) Is that the only way to do it?  Destroying and redrawing seems so wasteful.  2) Do I still approve your answer post even though it didn't contain the exact answer?  If you want to edit it or add a new post with the destroy / redraw solution, I'll approve that.  PS I'm new here.  :)

Comment: 1) So far, yes. I am asking the same question and I keep seeing that destroying is best solution I found. 2) Yes, please approve this solution. People will see our comments and figure it out :) I will update the solution to include the destroy solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting the error on that line is because you've got your syntax a little off in this line:

```
$('#tree').jstree.refresh(data.inst.get_selected());
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#tree').jstree("refresh", data.inst.get_selected());
```

Comment: I tried that, it seemed to trigger the refresh event, but:
1) The root of the displayed tree was the same as at the start.  I would have expected it to be the selected node.
2) The selected node lost all its children.

Comment: Furthermore, even though the refresh event was triggered, the tree **didn't** collapse fully.  So I'm not sure if this counts as a "proper" refresh.