# How to create an updatable tree using jstree and knockout

Tags: knockout.js, jstree

I was hoping to use knockout to build an updatable jstree.  I am able to get the tree to render properly, but when I update one of my observable objects, the items in the tree do not update automatically as I would expect.  Has anyone else had any luck getting this to work?  I have an example jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rsparkyc/wj4Xx/

You can see that when the input field is updated, the corresponding span is updated, however the tree view remains unchanged.

Comment: You may need to destroy the tree and build it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194516/click-on-jstree-node-rebuild-tree-with-that-node-as-the-root/10200718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact the jstree is modifying the DOM from what Knockout expects to be inside the  tags.

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI.  It has a knockout based tree that is fairly easy to use.

Comment: I don't think I'm loosing anything by using that tree view, so that works for me.  Thanks.